# Android getting null values when reading geo Exif data

Tags: android, image, gps, exif

In my android app, I want to get the geotag (lat,long) info from a image. I have this code
but it always gets null values for the geo information. The other information reads perfectly fine. I have GPS from satellite setting enabled, and the geo tagging option in camera app enabled. Yet when I take a picture the geo info is null values. Does anyone know what is wrong?

My phone is Samsung Galaxy S2X with android 4.1.2 (SGH-T989D).

```
        try {
            String imagefile = MyImage.getPath(this, data.getData());
            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(imagefile);
             String exif="Exif: " + imagefile;
               exif += "\nIMAGE_LENGTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH);
               exif += "\nIMAGE_WIDTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH);
               exif += "\n DATETIME: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
               exif += "\n TAG_MAKE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);
               exif += "\n TAG_MODEL: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL);
               exif += "\n TAG_ORIENTATION: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
               exif += "\n TAG_WHITE_BALANCE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE);
               exif += "\n TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH);
               exif += "\n TAG_FLASH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH);
               exif += "\nGPS related:";
               exif += "\n TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP);
               exif += "\n TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP);
               exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LATITUDE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
               exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
               exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
               exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
               exif += "\n TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD);

               Toast.makeText(this,
                 "finished",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="common.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Comment: Have you made sure to add the location permissions to your manifest file? Most notably `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

Comment: Yes, I have those permissions.